# Refreshing ListView after deleting ListItems

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a list view, populated with several ListItems. I also have an Option Menu, which includes "Delete all items" button. When I hit this button, it calls for a method that deletes all items except the default and should also refresh the ListView.
This is the menu code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        ...
        case R.id.optMenuDeleteAllCategories:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete all categories?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    **deleteAllCategories();**
                }
```

This is the `deleteAllCategories()` method:

```
 public void deleteAllCategories()
{
    manager.deleteAllCategories();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So it does delete everything, but the ListView doesn't refresh. I have to quit the app and reopen it to see the change. I also tried to put the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` line right after calling for `deleteAllCategories` method, but the ListView still didn't refresh.

So how can I refresh it without quitting the app?

Comment: If you deleted data from adapter, you could set this adapter to listView again: listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: No need of setting adapter again.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method exist to stop this recalling

Comment: what kind of adapter is in the list and how do you set the contents of the adapter? From the snippet I don't see where you actually change the data inside the adapter.

Comment: @ct_rob It's a ListView layout with an image and TextView, and it receives the data from the DB: `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(this, R.layout.category_item,
    R.id.txtCategoryName, lstAllCategories);` where lstAllCategories is an ArrayList holding a <Category> object. `lstAllCategories = manager.getAllCategories();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call adapter.clear() inside the deleteAllCategories method to also delete the items from the list.

Edit: The ArrayAdapter internally will work on different list instances then the one you passed in. So while changes to the objects inside your original list will be reflected, changes to the ArrayList you passed in will not be visible to the adapter.

You need to use the add, insert, remove and clear methods of the ArrayAdapter to modify the list in the adapter.

Comment: edited my answer to better clarify the reason for the fix i suggested

Comment: The problem is I'm deleting all items in the list except for one. This one item must stay in the list. My deleteAllCategories method in the manager looks like that: `String deleteAllCategories = "DELETE FROM " + CATEGORIES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE _id > 1;";` So isn't there a way to keep this only item and refresh the list?

Comment: If your data comes from a DB you might also want to check if a CursorAdapter might be better suited for your task (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

Comment: I solved the problem - I had to repopulate the list after calling for deleting method in the manager. `manager.deleteAllCategories();
    
    lstAllCategories = manager.getAllCategories();
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(this, R.layout.category_item,
    R.id.txtCategoryName, lstAllCategories);
  setListAdapter(adapter);` Thank you very much for your help!